# autocomplete get data from database didn't work

Tags: html, css, codeigniter

hye,I want to do the autocomplete for a system. I review a tutorial from here -> [http://cahbagusnongkrong.blogspot.my/2016/11/membuat-autocomplete-dari-database.html.]

the problem is my autocomplete still didn't works eventho I do the same as the tutorial did (just change the name)

so here is my controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Kepakaran_m');
    $this->load->helper('url', 'form');   

}

public function index()
{   $this->load->helper('form');
    $autocomp_bidang = $this->Kepakaran_m->get_bidang();
    $this->template->set('autocomp_bdg', $autocomp_bidang);
    $this->template->set('kepakaran',$kepakaran_staff);
    $this->template->render('profil/profilpersonal');

}  



public function get_bidang() {    
    $keyword = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $data = $this->dbsmk->from('kexpt103kodbidang')->like('bidang',$keyword)->get();            

    foreach($data->result() as $row)
    {
        $arr['query'] = $keyword;
        $arr['suggestions'][] = array(
            'value'    =>$row->bidang
        );
    }
    echo json_encode($arr);
}
```

and my model is as written below :

```
 function get_bidang(){

 $sql= "SELECT bidang FROM kexpt103kodbidang ORDER BY bidang";

    $query = $this->dbsmk->query($sql);
    return $query->result();}
```

my view is here :

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
     <div class="form-group">    
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <input type="text" class="form-control autocomplete" name="bidang" id="bidang" autofocus/>
         </div>
     </div>
  </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var site = "<?php echo site_url();?>";
$(function(){
    $('#bidang').autocomplete({
        serviceUrl: site+'expert/get_bidang',
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to debug your functionality. First check is your controller working.

You can try below code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var site = "<?php echo site_url();?>";
$(function(){

    $('#bidang').autocomplete({
        serviceUrl: site+'expert/get_bidang/'+$(this).val()
    });
});
</script>
```

You need to pass value for keyword. Also try to check using firebug which URL actually being called.

Try to debug by printing results before sending from controller. You can also try with static array from controller.

Let me know if any issue in debugging.